# One-sample t test for the non-significant Shapiro-Wilk variables, else Wilcoxon

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, batch-normalization

One of the reviewers for my paper did not understand why I compared the analyses to zero. Can you please help me understand if what I do does not make sense or if it does and I just need to convey the methods better.

I have 15 variables. I have carried out a content analysis to identify if these variables are discussed in a sample of experts. The data file consists of all 15 variables and the number of times it was discussed by each expert.
Instead of only reporting/describing the frequencies, I want to infer the variable's significance; that is, is the variable significantly discussed more than zero.

Thus I test for these hypotheses:
Null: the variable (v1-v12) is not significant from zero. 
Alternative: the variable is significantly different from zero.

The sample size is n = 10. Because of the low sample size and theory, I find it better to use a more strict alpha level to lower the chance for type 1 errors. (In this work, I would rather make a type 2 error, meaning I am not researching a potential cure for cancer). Thus alpha 0.001/99 % CI.

### Statistical procedure

1. Checking for assumptions. Especially normality. I perform a Shapiro-Wilk test. I find that 11 out of the 15 fail the Shapiro-Wilk test, implying the I cannot reject non-normality. Conclusion: I will run a one-sample t-test for these 11 variables, the other 4 I will run a one-sample Wilcoxon test.
2. Run one-sample t-test for the 11 where I compare the mean of each variable to zero.
3. Run Wilcoxon test where I compare the (rank/median/something else?)of each variable to zero.

I run these tests in spss.

### Inference

For each variable with a p-value higher than 0.001, I fail to reject the null. Thus, I cannot support that this particular variable is meaning in the context of my research. However, for the variables that are sig.different from zero, I have evidence that the variable is meaningful in this context.

The result, however, was 11, which is good news when applying the theoretical framework in the new context, where I suggest that the 11 variables also apply in this context. (due to sample size etc., I am of course careful in the conclusions).

I appreciate and welcome any reflections.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "the variable significantly discussed more than zero"?  This *sounds* like your null hypothesis is that the chance of discussing the variable is zero, in which case observing a single discussion of that variable would be significant evidence against the null.  That's obviously not a terribly useful conclusion, so what are you really trying to test?

Comment: For some of the variables, some experts did not discuss the variable at all (the participant's score was zero),but other experts did discuss that variable(e.g variable mean is 0.6). I wanted to statistically infer if a variable was discussed enough times to be significantly different from zero (null hypothesis = zero statements). When I run the calculations, I find that I cannot reject the possibility of zero statements in four of the variables. In my mind, then, it means that I don't have enough evidence to assume that these four have some significance in this work? Does it make sense at all?

Comment: I'm having trouble making sense of it because the existence of a *single* observation of something demonstrates the rate is nonzero.  I guess I'm suggesting that formally testing whether something is "significantly different from zero" is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: I understand. This is what I needed to hear, thank you. Perhaps it will be better to present and discuss the descriptives instead. I just wanted something less subjective than only looking at the descriptive mean when I suggest that the four variables are not enough discussed to be meaningful as of now. Like, how to determine if mean of 4, 5, 6, 7 is the cut-off. It would be subjective and I wanted a more "powerful" conclusion. I thought with these inferential statistics that I had something more to base my conclusions on as it also evaluate stuff like variance and sample size etc.